# Is it possible to hide stories in Storybook on the sidebar? But still be able to access them by URL?

Tags: storybook

I'm trying to do some stuff in Storybook.
I have a component called Button and there are too many stories on the sidebar.

[image]

Is there a way to be able to "hide" the stories on the sidebar but having the stories still loading in? So basically for example if I could hide the "With Text Only" story but have the story is loaded in so you could still access it at the url "http://localhost:9001/?path=/story/ccfk-%F0%9F%A7%A9-%E2%A0%80components-button--with-text-only" or access it using addon-links.

I'm unsure if this is possible or not and would really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's late but you can check this: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9209#issuecomment-586422011

Answer (score 2):

You can add a style with `display: none` for the story id in `manager-head.html`. This will hide the story link from side panel(but doesn't remove it from accessing it from URL).

Each side panel item has the css id same as the story id. So if you want to hide a button/withTextOnly story then below style in `.storybook/manager-head.html` will hide it.

`<style>#components-button--with-text-only { display: none;}</style>`

Comment: Thanks, Amith. Nice simple workaround. I hope at some point this gets included as a proper features for Storybook

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916166/10297155), Amith!

It's too bad that Storybook doesn't allow us to specify '[docsMode](https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.5/api/main-config-docs#docsmode)' at the story level, which would easily support this scenario :(

I wanted to add that another way to implement your workaround is by adding a style to the `.storybook\main.js` configuration, if somebody is not already using a `.storybook/manager-head.html` file. That's the case for me, and here's how I handled it:

**.storybook\main.js**

```js
const config = {
    'stories': [
        ...
    ],

    docs: {
        autodocs: true,
    },

    managerHead: (head) => `
        ${head}
        <style>a[id$="--docs-only"] { display: none; }</style>
    `,

    ...
};

export default config;
```

**MyComponent.stories.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
...

export default {
    ...
};

export const DocsOnly = {};
```

The `a[id$="--docs-only"]` CSS selector in `.storybook\main.js` will match any DOM element with an `id` that ends with `--docs-only`, which is the pattern that Storybook produces for any story exports that are named `DocsOnly` (as seen in my `MyComponent.stories.js` example).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ozman's answer which works great for me...

I changed the selector in head CSS to `div[data-item-id$="--docs-only"]` to hide the entire sidebar item, not just the